# Do I need to bundle files when publishing a library to npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

My project structure very very roughly looks like this:

```
dist/
  - helper.compiled.js
  - entrypoint.compiled.js
src/
 - helper.js
 - entrypoint.js
```

I was reading the npm publishing guidelines and it says to provide a single index.js file. But is this really necessary? Afterall, my `entrypoint.compiled.js` can just require `helper.compiled.js`. What is the benefit of providing a single `index.js` file?

What is the recommended procedure for publishing a library to npm in this situation? I tried using `npm pack`, but I don't quite understand what it is doing.

Comment: When publishing a library include the files or the folder in the [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) section of the `package.json`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to bundle just the compiled files is to put the directory in the [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) section of your `package.json`. This will then only package the files that npm uses such as `package.json`, `README.md`, and other files that your package requires.

An example `package.json` looks something like this:

```
{
    "name": "my-library",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "My Library.",
    "main": "dist/entrypoint.compiled.js",
    "scripts": {},
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {},
    "files": [
        "dist"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I see, so therefor, I don't need to bundle all my compiled files into a single index.js?

Comment: You shouldn't have to. if the compiled files work locally, then it will work when downloaded.

Comment: I do this in my package: https://npm.runkit.com/%40horsepower%2Fserver (Click "Browse files" on the top right.)

Comment: I guess I am worried that by not having a `index.js` file, users will have to do `require('my-lib-name/entrypoint.compiled.js')` instead of just `require('my-lib-name')` because I know node makes "index.js" the default file that is required when you require a directory.

Comment: It is based on the `main` property in the `package.json`. Just point that to the file you want to act as the `index.js`.

Comment: For trial-running my library, can I just unzip the resulting tarball into my node_modules?

Comment: yeah... `npm package` will create the tarball. You can then copy the files it has into `node_modules/my-package/`

Answer (score 0):

You need only to publish the compiled files. If you compile them correctly then there is no need to include your `src/` folder in the package.

Here is my `.npmignore` file for my tree in react package: [`.npmignore`](https://github.com/brumik/react-wooden-tree/blob/master/.npmignore) You can see what is in the package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-wooden-tree).

As you can see, I publish only the `dist` directory and every file in the root. The bare minimum is the `package.json` and the `dist` directory.

`npm publish` command essentially just creates a package from your files and uploads it to the npm registry. After running the command you will be able to find the npm package and use it as any other package.

After you run `npm publish` I recommend downloading published the package from the registry and try out if all the required files are there and verify that you can use everything.

Comment: Don't use `.npmignore` to include files in the package, use the [`files`](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#files) property in the `package.json`